# Type Error: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have a profile model and I want to just the owner of the profile can see it and update it . I'm writing my own permission for that but I have that error what should I do?? Type Error: 'bool' object is not callable

```
#views.py
class ProfileRetrieveUpdateView (generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)



#permissions
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Comment: Which line is the error in?

Comment: in this line :  return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()

Comment: I found the problem thank you. I should remove the ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Comment: yes it works please rate my question to help others to solve their same problems and I get reputation

Comment: Well, this is already mentioned in the doc. After django 1.8, the is_authenticated identifier was changed from a function to a property.